# Background only covers half of the page on mobile

Tags: css, background

It is all fine when i open it through my pc browser

I have changed the height to 350%, it works, covered all of the screen, but the image turns to be so stretched out. I have changed the background-size to contain, it doesnt work.

```
{background-image: url(bg.jpg) ;

background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 100% 100%
```

this it what it looks like
[image: this it what it looks like]
Image ends here

it even looks worse, when i switch to desktop mode
[image: it even looks worse, when i switch to desktop mode]

Image ends here

Comment: please provide the html code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time and visit [SO Asking Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and must read[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding min-height to 100vh..Maybe it helps

Add this css code to your div

min-height : 100vh;

Comment: Try experimenting with different viewport heights. You may set it to 50vh or some other Value that you find is feasible

Answer (score 0):

Your best option here would be to use a media query for mobile sizes and either another picture with an aspect ratio set for mobiles, or to have the background-positions and size changed to suit for phone. Code below to get you started.

```
/*--For Desktop--*/

body{
    background-image: url(bg.jpg) ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)  {
    body{
        background-image: url(theotherimage-withnewaspectratio.jpg);
    }
}
```

Also - max-width i'd change based on when your image starts to look dodgy on desktop rather than the 600px (just shrink your screen in developer mode to tell the pixel width)

Comment: @Sleepwalker be more specific. Are you using it wrong? the media queries literally change sites completely based on defined sizes, and this case here is pretty much one of the reasons why they exist

Comment: @Sleepwalker also note, any items you define above the media query will be present inside it unless its specifically overwritten

Answer (score 0):

Change background-size to cover instead of 100% 100% i think this will help you some how